# probability of having infinite number of prime

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

I am reading `MATH PUZZLES Vol. 3 by PRESH TALWALKAR`. To be specific, if there are infinite number of primes in the set `{2,5,8,11,...}`.

Now suppose $a,b \in  \mathbb{Z}^+$ and we have a set $\mathbb{A} = \{a,a+b,a+2b,...\}$ . What is the probability that it has infinite number of primes?

For example, if $a,b \in [1,2]$ then $ p = \frac{3}{4}$. I was wondering if this probability converges as the range extends.

Comment: There are an infinite number of primes as long as $a$ and $b$ aren't both even. The probability is 3/4

Comment: The Dirichlet-theorem tells us that the arithmetic progression $a+nb$, $a,b>0$ and $n$ running over the naturals contains infinite many primes if and only if $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(a,b)=1$ then by Dirichlet's theorem of infinitude of primes in an arithmetic progression, the sequence has infinite primes, and if $(a,b)\neq 1$, then of course the sequence has finite number of primes as the sequence is increasing and all of it's terms will be divisible by the GCD, hence your question boils down to, what is the probability that if two randomly chosen natural numbers are co-prime.

It's a famous problem and the ans is $6/\pi^2$.